# COTS router as both wireless client and access point and separate SSIDs

Tags: networking, wireless, router, wlan

I am searching for a commercial off the shelf device, or list of devices, or general name of the appliance, that perform(s) the following:

- Has at least two radios that can be configured such that one is a wireless client to a a "WAN" network, and the other is an access point to a private network that the router manages (DHCP, gateway, etc.)
- At least one physical ethernet port on the private network as the wireless access point.
- Router provides NAT internet access for the private network (WAP and physical ethernet clients) to the wireless "WAN".
- Of course, WAP and physical ethernet clients on the private network can communicate with each other.

I am able to do this with DD-WRT rather effortlessly, but as DD-WRT is not considered robust, it does not satisfy the requirements I've been handed (and of course there is the issue with robustness of SOHO products in general). I'm afraid I can't go into detail about why the above setup is necessary, suffice it to say that after long discussions it is decidedly the only setup that will work in our situation.

Although this may be a niche use case, it does seem like such a device should have a market and so not be difficult to find, but my google capabilities appear to have failed me here.